# How can I pass values from different multiple arrays to a new single array?

Tags: c++

My code:

```
void Block::word()
{
    std::string worda[] = {"cat","owl","cow"};
    std::string wordb[] = {"apple","power","block"};
    std::string wordc[] = {"account","extreme","kingdom"};
    std::string wordd[] = {"adjective","undefined","pineapple"};

    srand(time(0));
    fnwords[0] = worda[rand() % 3 + 1];
    fnwords[1] = wordb[rand() % 3 + 1];
    fnwords[2] = wordc[rand() % 3 + 1];
    fnwords[3] = wordd[rand() % 3 + 1];

    for (int d=0; d<4; d++){
          std::cout << fnwords[d] << std::endl;
      }
}

int main()
{
    Block obj;
    obj.word();
    return 0;
}
```

Here the first index of array `fnwords` must contain a random word from array `worda`, second index from `wordb`, and so on.

But it gives error sometimes that program.exe has stopped working.

And it initializes array like this:

```
-cow
-cat
-kingdom
-undefined
```

Comment: Indexing starts at 0, `rand() % 3` gives 0, 1, or 2. Don't `+ 1`

Comment: Where are `Block` and `fnwords` defined?  Where are the includes for `<string>`, `<iostream>` and `<cstdlib>`?  Please edit your code to make it a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Well it was a very big code to write here....

Comment: rand () % 3 worked for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to `rand()` call. You are using arrays with length of 3. However, `rand()%3` returns one of the following set: {0, 1, 2} which are the only valid values to index your array. When you `+1` to this index, it gives you {1, 2, 3} where index 3 is an invalid index.

Comment: @Mr.Developer Good news :)